# how to remove a particular key => value from a session array?

Tags: php

let's say i have $_SESSION['cart']; when I print this

```
echo "<pre>",print_r($_SESSION['cart']),"</pre>";
```

it will show something like

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
)
```

where the keys are the product IDs and the value is the quantity of each product.
so, if I would want to delete product no. 2  from that session array, 
how am to do that ?

I tried the fastest function that came to my mind

```
 public function removeItem($id2){
   foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty) {
        if ($id == $id2){
         unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);

      }
   }
 }
```

it deleted the whole $_SESSION['cart'] data :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id2]);
```

You don't need to walk through whole array in foreach for this. Simple is better than complicated :)

Comment: i tried that and it removed the particular product..but the last product remaining, can't be removed, why is that ?

Comment: what do you mean saying "can't be removed"?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you looping through? If you get the id you want do delete as a parameter anyway, you can do this:

```
public function removeItem($id2) {
  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the id just do :

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$id] = null;
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

just do

```
public function removeItem($id){
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
}
```